# ¿Cómo sumar datos de inputs dinámicos?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

mi pregunta quizás ya este hecha muchas veces pero no puedo solucionarlo he intentado muchas cosas pero no doy con el resultado, tengo que sumar inputs que se generan dinamicamente cuando el usuario da clic sobre un botón, estos tienen que sumarse para comprobar si se ha pasado de la cantidad que un ticket tiene, pero por alguna razón me suma N cantidad de veces el contenido de la misma caja o no entiendo que pasa, esto es lo que tengo al momento.

> En este parte genero el input dinámico y se pueden crear N cantidad de inputs.

```
var fila = "<tr><td>" + USERID + "</td><td>" 
    + DISPNAME + 
    "</td><td><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-3'><input type='text' name='piezas' id='piezas' class='form-control piezas'></div></div></td><td><button class='btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-danger m-b-5' id='delete'> <i class='fa fa-remove'></i> </button></td></tr>";
    $("#tabla-2 tbody").append(fila);
```

> En esta parte obtengo las piezas totales que tiene el ticket y cuantos inputs fueron generados, los divido para obtener las piezas por input, lo asigno a los input.

```
    var piezas = $('#table-1 tbody tr').find('td').eq(6).text();
    var noEmp = $("#tabla-2 tbody tr").length;
    empxpiezas = piezas/noEmp;
    var resultado = 0;
    $("input[name='piezas']").each(function(indice, valor) {
      piezasTo = $(this).val(empxpiezas); 

      $("input[name='piezas']").change("keypress",function(){
        posicion = $(this).val();
        resultado += resultado + Number($(this).val());

        $("#sumatotalticket").text(resultado);
      });


  });
```

> Posterior a asignar el resultado de la operación hago una función de evento change para que detecte cuando el valor cambia (es decir cuando el usuario modifica la cantidad de forma manual) y se realice la suma automáticamente, pero no entiendo que es lo que pasa y al parecer como dije anteriormente, suma N cantidad de veces la misma caja.

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

> Este es parte de mi HMTL (LA PARTE IMPORTANTE ES LA TABLA DESPUES DEL TITULO TICKETS A REPARTIR EL BULTO)

```
    <hr>
<div class="page-header" style="text-align:center;">
  <h3>Empleados a repartir el Ticket <p style="text-align:right; font-size:14px;">SUMA TOTAL: <b id="sumatotalticket"></b></p></h3>
</div>
<div class="scroll">
<table id="tabla-2" class="table table-striped tabla-2">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Codigo</th>
<th>Nombre de Empleado</th>
<th>Piezas por empleado</th>
<th>Acciones</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

> Asi se muestra el HTML
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar el HTML para hacer una representación de tu ejercicio?

Comment: @VickMuñoz listo pero solo coloque una parte porque esta mas amplio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let contenedor = $('#contenedor');
  let resultado = $('#resultado');
  let input = `<input type="text" class="inputs"><br>`;
  $([1,2,3,4]).each(function(value, key){
   contenedor.append(input);
  });
  let allinputs = $('.inputs');
  let values = [];
  $('#sum').on('click', function(){
   allinputs.each((value, key)=>{
    values.push($(key).val());
   });
    let sum = values.reduce((pv,cv)=>{
     return pv + (parseFloat(cv)||0);
 },0);
    resultado.html(`la suma de los inputs es: ${sum}`);
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">
 
</div>
<button id="sum">sumar</button>
<label id="resultado"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como sumar inputs de forma dinamica.

```js
    
    $(document).on('click', '#agregarinput', function()
    {
     event.preventDefault();
    
     var num = $('.piezas').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
     
        // inserto el nuevo input
        $('#piezas' + num).after('<input type="number" class="piezas" name="piezas'+newNum+'" id="piezas'+ newNum +'" value=0>');
          
    });
    
    $(document).on('keyup', '.piezas', function(){
     var resultado = 0;
     
          // sumas todos los inputs
     $(".piezas").each(function() {      
      resultado += parseInt($(this).val());
     });
     // pasas el resultado      
     $("#resultado").val(resultado); 
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <a id="agregarinput" href="">Agregar</a><br>
    
    <input type="number" class="piezas" name="piezas1" id="piezas1" value=0><br><br>
    
    <input type="number" name="resultado" id="resultado"><br><br>
```